# Relational table that is constrained to a subset of its referee

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, subset

Say I have the following table:

```
create table foo (
  id    integer  primary key,
  mode  integer  not null check (mode in (1, 2))
);
```

Now I want to store additional information about records from this table, but only those that have, say, `mode = 1`. The way I thought I could do this is as follows:

```
create table foo_bar (
  id      integer  primary key,
  foo_id  integer,
  _mode   integer  not null default (1) check (_mode = 1),

  foreign key (foo_id, _mode) references foo(id, mode)
);
```

That is, we have a dummy column in `foo_bar` that is forcibly always equal to 1 and include that in the foreign key constraint with `foo`.

However, not only does this not work (with `pragma foreign_keys = ON;`), but that foreign key constraint can be violated when you insert multiple values into `foo`!

```
sqlite> insert into foo(mode) values (1);
sqlite> insert into foo(mode) values (2);
sqlite> select * from foo;
1|1
2|2
sqlite> insert into foo_bar(foo_id) values (1);
Error: foreign key mismatch - "foo_bar" referencing "foo"
sqlite> insert into foo_bar(foo_id) values (2);
Error: foreign key mismatch - "foo_bar" referencing "foo"
sqlite> insert into foo(mode) values (1), (2);
Error: foreign key mismatch - "foo_bar" referencing "foo"
```

Is this a bug in SQLite (I'm using 3.17, it it matters), or am I doing it wrong?

An alternative option, without the foreign key, might be to use a trigger:

```
create trigger bad_mode
before insert on foo_bar when (select mode from foo where id = NEW.foo_id) <> 1
begin
  select raise(fail, "Invalid mode");
end;
```

...but this seems a bit gross!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) says:

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index.

That missing UNIQUE constraint is what causes the "foreign key mismatch" error.

---

It is not possible to use a subquery in a CHECK constraint, so the only way to enforce the `mode = 1` constraint is to make it part of the foreign key constraint, or to use triggers.

Comment: Useful to know... Although, now after all this, I'm tempted to just normalise away the problem! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could improve the design, and no constraints other than FK are needed:

- First of all `foo.mode` could be a foreign key to another table, say `modes`, no need to use a check constraint. You would store the values 1 and 2 there.
- A second table, say `bar_modes`, could have a field `mode`, a FK to `modes`. You would store the value 1 in this table.
- Finally, `foo_bar.foo_id` would be FK to `foo.id`, and `foo_bar.mode` a FK to `bar_modes.mode`.

Let me know what you think!

**SQL Server example for M = 3, N = 5**

```
create table modes (
    id int primary key
)

create table foo (
  id    int  primary key,
  mode  int  not null foreign key references modes(id)
);

create table bar_modes (
  id int primary key foreign key references modes(id)
)

create table foo_bar (
  id int primary key,
  foo_id int foreign key references foo(id),
  other_data varchar(20)
)

insert modes (id) values(1)
insert modes (id) values(2)
insert modes (id) values(3)
insert modes (id) values(4)
insert modes (id) values(5)

insert bar_modes (id) values (1)
insert bar_modes (id) values (2)
insert bar_modes (id) values (3)

insert foo (id, mode) values (1000, 1)
insert foo (id, mode) values (2000, 2)
insert foo (id, mode) values (2500, 2)
insert foo (id, mode) values (5000, 5)

insert foo_bar (id, foo_id, other_data) values (100, 1000, 'data for foo 1000')
insert foo_bar (id, foo_id, other_data) values (200, 2000, 'data for foo 2000')
insert foo_bar (id, foo_id, other_data) values (250, 2500, 'data for foo 2500')
```

Comment: Thanks. The check on `foo.mode` was just to illustrate my point; in my actual schema, I do have a "modes" table that I reference, as you suggest. Anyway, I think a different schema is probably the way to go, but instead of how you suggest, I think I would break out the mode relation into a new table. This works for my use case, where I'm only interested in one mode in the subset, but it isn't a general solution.

Comment: What is the general problem, for which your are looking for a general solution?

Comment: I'm not looking for a general solution, but say for example you had N modes and `foo_bar` only allowed records from `foo` from M modes (where M<=N). For M=1 (my case), you could achieve this by having a new table that links records from `foo` with modes and then just FK to `foo.id` (but you'd lose any implicit semantics in the schema); if M=N, then it's even more trivial as you'd just FK to the ID and mode from the original table (no extra table required). However, when 1<M<N, neither solution work; and neither will yours, as it's important that the composite key of ID and mode is preserved.

Comment: I am editing the answer to append SQL code (SQL server), see it live [here](http://rextester.com/DXG30944). Can you explain where is the problem? In my example, M = 3 and N = 5. And no, I don't see how any semantics are lost this way.

Comment: `insert foo_bar (id, foo_id, other_data) values (300, 5000, 'data for foo 5000')` works, but it should be a constraint failure. The point of `foo_bar` is that it only allows `foo.id` records whose `mode` is 1, 2 or 3. Your schema has no constraint at all for that. [My method of using a composite FK works](http://rextester.com/UVUMU20702), but interestingly it seems MS SQL Server has the same problem as SQLite as pointed out by @CL. That is, the foreign reference fields need to be defined as either a composite primary key or unique.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add foo_bar.mode to the schema. I will try to rework it now.

Comment: Don't worry about it and thanks for your input. No need to spend extra time on it as a solution has been found.